# Unable to integrate twitter-kit-android in my App using Android Studio 3.1/3.2 Canary

Tags: android

When I was trying to integrate Twitter kit into my project, unable to run the project with the latest version of android studio 3.2 canary.

Below is the Gradle build file.

## build.gradle (module: app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.rrr.xxx"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

        /**
         * Twitter dependencies
         */
        implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:+@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
    }
```

## Error:

Error message in gradle console.

> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/tweet-composer-3.2.0.aar/fa1e13c6247ce33b4da03df71a7b3606/jars/classes.jar

## Log from Build console:

Below are the build console messages.

```
build failed    4s 335ms
Run build   4s 267ms
Load build  2ms
Configure build 116ms
Calculate task graph    21ms
Run tasks   4s 123ms
null    
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/tweet-composer-3.2.0.aar/fa1e13c6247ce33b4da03df71a7b3606/jars/classes.jar    
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.  
com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete 
com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException   
null    
Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that library has moved to Java 8, try to enable Java 8 language in your build.gradle.

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```